Pymongo push operation overriding in Python
I am trying to do the following operation concurrently across many machine
 operation = {"$push": {field_name: task}}
 result = table.find_one_and_update({'_id': _id}, operation, return_document=pymongo.collection.ReturnDocument.AFTER)

but somehow the field i am trying to push to is getting overridden is this possible given i assumed pushing would never overwrite that is the reason which i picked that specific operation.
Does the find_one_and_update not provide a lock at the reading time
that could be the only reason I can think of but could gather any evidence to support or oppose the same.
The case that comes to mind is:
Client A reads the document where field is [].
Client B also reads the document where field is []. not locked so can read
Client A pushes 'task1' to field and updates the document to ['task1'].
Client B pushes 'task2' to field, but since it read the original state ([]), it overwrites the array, resulting in ['task2'].

So two operations are still atomic they are updating what they are reading, but they not locked at the read level.
PyMongo version 4.5.0
MongoDB atlas version 6.0.16
Python version 3.8

Is field_name really "[]"?

field_name being the field and the [] is the value for the field i understand the wording is confusing for the same
